# How to remove or disable empty cart button confirmation popup in Magento2 - 2.4.5

Tags: magento2, cart, magento2.4.5

We've recently updated a customer Magento2 to 2.4.5-p5, now the cart page added a confirmation popup when clicking the empty cart button:

**Magento_Checkout/js/shopping-cart.js**

```
        _confirmClearCart: function () {
            var self = this;

            confirm({
                content: $.mage.__('Are you sure you want to remove all items from your shopping cart?'),
                actions: {
                    /**
                     * Confirmation modal handler to execute clear cart action
                     */
                    confirm: function () {
                        self.clearCart();
                    }
                }
            });
        },
```

We'd like to remove the confirmation popup so the button empties the cart straight away, any idea on the fastest and simplest approach to doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to override the default behavior of the method triggering the modal is to copy the js file to the theme:

Copy this file:
**vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/shopping-cart.js**

To your theme:
**app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Checkout/web/js/shopping-cart.js**

And redefine the method content:

```
        _confirmClearCart: function () {
            this.clearCart();
        },
```